# I want to access the attribute of xml tag using javascript, how I can access it?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am getting the XML data from link "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=CHXX0008&u=unit"

Following is my javscript code :

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?"+"p="+zipcode+"&u=c",
           dataType: "xml",
           success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('channel').each(function(){ 

                } 
             } } );
```

[image]

Using above code I am trying to access "city" attribute of tag "yweather:location". How can I accesss? Please check the XML data using link provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(xml) {
                var loc = xml.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0', 'location');
                var city = loc[0].getAttribute('city');
                console.log(city);
            }
```

Hope this helps you. Mark as answer if you are satisfied.